# Terraform how to read the run time values ..Cloudformation equivalent of Instrinsic functions

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

AWS CloudFormation provides several built-in functions that help you manage your stacks. Use intrinsic functions in your templates to assign values to properties that are not available until runtime.

What is equivalent to these functions in Terraform? like for example in Cloudformation we have Fn::ImportValue . what is equivalent in Terraform?

thank you

Comment: Data sources...

Comment: I will read up. thank you

Answer (score 1):

The CloudFormation function [`Fn::ImportValue`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html) is for reading an exported value from another CloudFormation stack, and so its *closest* analog in Terraform would be [the `aws_cloudformation_export` data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/cloudformation_export), included in the `hashicorp/aws` provider.

```
data "aws_cloudformation_export" "subnet_id" {
  name = "SubnetID"
}
```

With the a data resource declared as above, an expression like `data.aws_cloudformation_export.subnet_id.value` elsewhere in your module would be similar to the following CloudFormation expression:

```
{"Fn::ImportValue": "SubnetID"}
```

Terraform is a little different than CloudFormation in that expressions themselves are generally "inert", referring only to data exported from other objects in the configuration, and so the `data` block tells Terraform that you expect to find that object in your AWS account, separately from potentially multiple uses of it.

With that said, I'm not sure if you are asking specifically about CloudFormation exports or if you are asking generally about loading information about objects defined in other Terraform configurations. If you meant the more general question, then the Terraform Language mechanism for this is [Data Sources](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/data-sources/index.html), which `aws_cloudformation_export` was an example of. All Terraform providers can offer data sources to retrieve information from different sources, and so in that sense the Terraform mechanism is more general than the CloudFormation feature you referred to.